# Facebook: moderate "works at" your business page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

We're running our company business page. Sometimes, one of us wants to share something with just the colleagues, so when posting he/she selects Custom as a post audience, and then selects business page name. This seems to limit the audience to whoever has selected "Works At" [our business page] in their profile. This is all fine.

However, I cannot find a way to moderate this in any way. We have ex-employees still carrying that tag, and anyone else could also improperly set it.

How can we remove/administer/see who has set "Works At" to our page?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to moderate this, and frankly I don't know of any site who does - take for example LinkedIn, Facebook, Angel.co, etc.

It's best to maybe email those who you think are doing this incorrectly and hope that they change it. Nothing much you can do!